# Thymeleaf accessing DOM element properties

Tags: spring-boot, dom, thymeleaf

I'm using `thymeleaf 3` with `SpringBoot 2.1.3` webapp project. I would like to solve the problem that occurs when, inside a form, an `input type select` is `disabled` and the selected data is not send through the POST.

I would like to do something like that inside thymeleaf page:

```
<select th:field="*{datiSocietariDto.provincia}" id="provincia" th:disabled="disabled">
  <option value="" selected>PROVINCIA</option>
  <option th:each="city : ${tipologicalDto.cities}" th:value="${city.descrizione}" th:text="${city.descrizione}"></option>
</select>

<span th:if=[provincia is disabled]>
  <input type="hidden" th:value=[value of selected option]>
</span>
```

I don't know how to retrieve te information inside square brackets and if is it possible to do something like this with `thymeleaf`. I could solve this using JQuery but is really not very elegant solution.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to read the disabled state of another tag in Thymeleaf. Your options are:

1. Use readonly instead of disabled.  Readonly elements cannot be edited but are still sent with a post.
2. Use some kind of variable, something like this for example:

   ```
   <th:block th:with="disabled=true">
       <select th:field="*{datiSocietariDto.provincia}" id="provincia" th:disabled="${disabled}">
         <option value="" selected>PROVINCIA</option>
         <option th:each="city : ${tipologicalDto.cities}" th:value="${city.descrizione}" th:text="${city.descrizione}"></option>
       </select>

       <input th:if="${disabled}" type="hidden" th:field="*{datiSocietariDto.provincia}">
   </th:block>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your support. I had the doubt that I could not do it with `Thymeleaf` but I don't want to create `JQuery inline elements` with selected values.

Now I'm trying with a simple workaround like this:

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
  $(this).find(':select').attr('disabled', false); ***
  $('#msform').submit();
});
```

It's still not correct, it's throw an error on *** row, i'm searching the correct sintax to find all `select input` inside my `form` and reabilitate it immediately before `submit` the `form` and evaluate if it's a working solution or not.

Anyway thanks again for your quick and precious support.